# Check boxes in a CheckedListBox from a predefined list of strings

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a checkedListBox (c#) and would like to have some of the boxes in it checked when the window is opened. I have a `List<string>` that contains values, and if a value in the list is the same as a value in the CheckedListBox, I want it checked!

I can get all the boxes to check themselves, but am having trouble with the next part. How do I check if a value in the listbox equals any of the values in the list?

Here's what I have so far:

```
//List of all the strings that I want to check
List<string> categories = new List<string>();
categories.Add("Cat 1");
categories.Add("Cat 2");
categories.Add("Cat 2");

//clBCategory is the CheckedListBox
for (int i = 0; i < clBCategory.Items.Count; i++)
     {
          clBCategory.SetItemChecked(i, true);
     }
```

Comment: have you considered searching the list ?

Comment: The question makes little sense, the user cannot add or remove items from the list.  So how could the List<> and the list box ever *not* contain the same values, unless you wrote the code to make them different.  The index of the item in the list box is the same index it has in the List<>

Comment: @HansPassant - I think the `categories` is intended to only contain a subset of the values possible to be checked in `clBCategory` and is only considered at application startup (like a list of defaults).

Comment: @HansPassant yes, the list of categories is filled at startup from a predefined set of values from a database. I wanted to check some of them depending on what inparameters the form has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CheckedListBox` is basically a loosly typed collection of `object` objects. The code below is pretty rough but should be enough to get you going:

```
List<string> categories = new List<sting>();
categories.Add("Cat 1");
categories.Add("Cat 2");
categories.Add("Cat 3");

for (int i = 0; i < clBCategory.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (categories.Contains(clBCategory.Items[i].ToString()))
        clBCategory.SetItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can do something like this,

```
      List<string> categories = new List<sting>();
      categories.Add("Cat 1");
      categories.Add("Cat 2");
      categories.Add("Cat 3");
      int index;

      //Instead of traversing checkedListBox1 I have traversed List
      foreach (string str in list)
      {
       index = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(str);
       if (index < 0) continue;
       if (str == checkedListBox1.Items[index].ToString())
        {
         checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
        }
      }
```

**I have tested it and it works perfectly fine :)**

2) Further more i would recommend you to use **collection initializer** like this

```
      list = new List<string>() {"Cat 1","Cat 2","Cat 9"};
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually not initializing the list as I wrote above, it's something like this: 
List<string> categories = controller.FindCategoiesByRecipe(rNumber);
But I thought it would be easier to red this way, for future beginners like me!
Thanks again!